# How do I clear all custom opts that I've set for HoloViews?

Tags: configuration, holoviews

How do I clear all custom `opts` that I've set for HoloViews, so that the default, out of the box, `opts` are used?

For example, if I've defined

```py
opts.defaults(
    opts.Scatter(color='blue',
                 hooks=[mpl_style_hook]),
    opts.Histogram(color='orange',
                 hooks=[mpl_style_hook]),
    opts.Bars(color='green',
                 hooks=[mpl_style_hook]),
    backend='matplotlib'
)
```

How can I completely remove all of the specified `opts` for `Scatter`, `Histogram` and `Bar`?

Answer (score 1):

Good question! I am not aware of any way to do that besides restarting Python, because I don't think we current store a copy of the original option tree. There may already be a way to save the option tree *before* setting those defaults and then restore it, but if so I don't know it! Feel free to file a feature request at https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues .

Comment: Is there a way to see what the current defaults are?